# How to wait for the worker processes in Python multiprocessing.pool.Pool without closing it?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm benchmarking this script on a 6-core CPU with Ubuntu 22.04.1 and Python 3.10.6. It is supposed to show usage of all available CPU cores with `par` function vs. a single core with `ser` function.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import timeit as ti


def foo(n):
  return -np.sort(-np.arange(n))[-1]


def par(reps, bigNum, pool):
  for i in range(bigNum, bigNum+reps):
    pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i,))


def ser(reps, bigNum):
  for i in range(bigNum, bigNum+reps):
    foo(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  bigNum = 9_000_000
  reps = 6

  fun = f'par(reps, bigNum, pool)'
  t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup='pool=Pool(reps);'+fun, globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=10))
  print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms')

  fun = f'ser(reps, bigNum)'
  t = 1000 * np.array(ti.repeat(stmt=fun, setup=fun, globals=globals(), number=1, repeat=10))
  print(f'{fun}:  {np.amin(t):6.3f}ms  {np.median(t):6.3f}ms')
```

Right now, `par` function only shows the time to spin the worker processes. What do I need to change in function `par`, in order to make it wait for all worker processes to complete before returning? Note that I would like to reuse the process pool between calls.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the result from apply_async to wait for it.

```py
def par(reps, bigNum, pool):
  jobs = []
  for i in range(bigNum, bigNum+reps):
    jobs.append(pool.apply_async(foo, args=(i,)))
  for job in jobs:
    job.get()
```

for long loops you should be using `map` or `imap` or `imap_unordered` instead of `apply_async` as it has less overhead and you get to control the chunksize for faster serialization of small objects, and you can pass generators to them to save memory or allow infinite generators (with imap).

```py
def par(reps, bigNum, pool):
    pool.map(foo, range(bigNum,bigNum+reps), chunksize=1)
```

note: python [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) indentation is 4 spaces, not 2.